# How to have "jQuery.Event" work on Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, keydown, keycode

I'm writing a script which triggers an artificial keydown event with keyCode 37 when
button is clicked.

The following script works fine on IE, Safari, and Chrome, but it doesn't work on Firefox and Opera. Even if I change **{keyCode: 37}** to **{which: 37}**, it still doesn't work.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
   jQuery("body").trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 37}));
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it work on Firefox and Opera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, if a browser doesn't support `which` , it will support `keyCode`

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var keyDownEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");
   if(keyDownEvent.which){
           keyDownEvent.which = 37;
   }else{
           keyDownEvent.keyCode = 37;
        } 
  $("body").trigger(keyDownEvent);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the above script, but it still doesn't work on Firefox and Opera although it works well on IE. I don't know why...

Comment: I changed Event("keydown") to Event("keypress") in the above script. Then it works on FireFox and Opera!! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way :

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
   e.which = 50;
  $("body").trigger(e);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the above script, but it still doesn't work on Firefox and Opera...